# how to display related image names in grid

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iPhone development. what i am doing is displaying 20 images as grid and each image treat as button .by selecting that image it will be displayed on image view but what i need is along with that image,image name also displayed at bottom how can i done this pls help me i am lucky if u give a sample code also thank u

Answer (score 0):

Put a label below the button.

Comment: good idea but please tell sample code how to add label below button

Comment: Just as you use UIButton to display an image, use UILabel for the text. If you are able to put a button on your view you should be able to use a UILabel for sure. Just position it below your button.